# How to nullify childre's foreign key when parent deleted using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have basic Flask application with `Parent` and `Child` models like that:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)


class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=db.backref('children', cascade='all,delete'))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

As database I am using Postgres if it is important.
Now I want to do following: remove `cascade='all,delete'` from child and make this `parent_id` nullable. I.e. when `Parent` removed from DB `Child` stays in place with `parent_id == NULL`.

I know that I could specify it with schema creation script adding constraint to FK. But I want just to mark it as `NULL` and allow SqlAlchemy take control on nullification of children's FK.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's explained in the [relevant section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/cascades.html?highlight=cascade#delete) of the documentation in a great detail. Make sure you also read "ORM-level “delete” cascade vs. FOREIGN KEY level “ON DELETE” cascade" section to understand differences between proposed solutions.

#### ORM level

> Now I want to do following: remove `cascade='all,delete'` from child and make this `parent_id` nullable.

Do it and you will get exact behaviour you want.

```
class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id'), nullable=True)
    parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=db.backref('children'))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

Also note, that `all` is the synonym for `save-update, merge, refresh-expire, expunge, delete`, so `all, delete` is the same as simply `all`.

#### DB level

If you want to have `ON DELETE SET NULL` constraint on the database level, you can specify [`ondelete='SET NULL'`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/constraints.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.params.ondelete) in the `ForeighKey` definition or do nothing (since it's default behaviour for the foreign key). To get it working on the DB level you also need to set [`passive_deletes`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes) to either `True` or `'all'` (see docs for the difference).

```
class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
    parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=db.backref('children', passive_deletes=True))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```